# LaTex table numbering

Tags: latex

How could I number the tables in my article chapter based ? So I want all the tables in the fifth section to be numbered like "Table 5.1", ..., "Table 5.n".

I tried

```
\usepackage{chngcntr}

\counterwithin{figure}{section}

\counterwithin{table}{section}

\counterwithin{equation}{section}
```

but I am having some problems (missing package I guess).

However, I need a simpler solution, without the need to use such packages.

Answer (score 3):

The article class doesn't have chapters.  Try the book or report classes - you'll find that the tables and figures are automatically numbered according to chapter.

Comment: But if he wants that notation in small paper, to which article class is dedicated, classes report and book are useless. Unless you tune them to appear as article (lists on new page, large titles for chapter, twoside margins,...). If the paper is longer, your recommend is best way.

Answer (score 2):

Here is a solution without the use of any package (courtesy of "The Latex Companion", A1.4):

```
\makeatletter
\renewcommand{\thetable}{\thesection.\@arabic\c@table}
\@addtoreset{table}{section}
\makeatother
```

This resets the table counter whenever a new section is started, and formats it as `sectionno.tableno` instead of just `tableno`. You can change the `figure` and `equation` counters similarly.

If you are using the `amsmath` package (or an AMS class like `amsart` that loads it automatically), you can use

```
\numberwithin{table}{section}
```

This was created for equations, but works for any pair of counters though supposedly there might be tricky situations that it does not handle well.

Comment: I would love to number my figures and tables in the amsmath package using \numberwithin{table}{section} but for every subsection, but \numberwithin{table}{subsection} completely removes the section number? Is this also possible?